# create a function and modify a post on the wordpress site based on the post id

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd want to edit the content of one of my posts using this way, but it's not working.

Does this filter affect the php output or the raw php file?

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'multiple_string_replacements');
function multiple_string_replacements ( $contentt ) {
    if ( is_single('15467') && in_the_loop() && is_main_query() ) {
   
    $condition = true;
  
    if($condition){
        $urlsdothejob = "link.com";
        
        $text = array(
        "$variable1" => "$urlsdothejob",
        "$variable2" => "$urlsdothejob",
    );

    $contentt = str_ireplace(array_keys( $text ), $text, $contentt);

    };
    }
    return $contentt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the conditions that you're looking for, you should be able to write an `IF` statement to match.

```
if ($constantvalue == "anothervalue") {
  // make local changes 
}
```

Can you give an example of what you're trying to do?  It's hard to understand the request with such little information.

Comment: I can make if statements, but I'm having trouble accessing a single post based on its id in the single.php file, which I'd want to update in this theme file, as in if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post()->$postid=2585): then do a file modification

Answer (score 0):

Try like this hope its working for you.

```
while(have_posts()):

    $ID = get_the_ID();

    $data1 = get_post_meta($ID,'meta_key',true);
    $data2 = get_post_meta($ID,'meta_key',true);

    if($data1 == $data2) {
        update_post_meta($ID,'meta_key','meta_value');
    }

endwhile;
```

Comment: thank you thats not my problem please check this . i use this filter                              
add_filter( 'the_content', 'multiple_string_replacements');
function multiple_string_replacements ( $contentt ) {
    if ( is_single('15467') && in_the_loop() && is_main_query() ) {
   
    $condition = true;
    if($condition){
  $urlsdothejob = "link.com";
        
  $text = array(
  "$variable1" => "$urlsdothejob",
  "$variable2" => "$urlsdothejob",
 );

 $contentt = str_ireplace(array_keys( $text ), $text, $contentt);

    };
    }
    return $contentt;
} not working

Comment: I don't think soo it work like that the way you using it